# Al solicitar un String desde Values me lo toma como int

Tags: android-studio, string, android-recyclerview

En Android Studio, al queres asignar texto desde Values String me señala que es un int y se muestra como numero.
Estoy dando valores a un Recyclerview desde String mas resultados de un Firestore:

la variable atitulo le asigno el valor de String, pero me marca error, me dice que es un entero, me sugiere que la declare como int o use String.valueOf

```
   @Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i, @NonNull Precio articulo) {

    String atitulo = R.string.Precio_Atitulo;
    viewHolder.textViewConsecutivo.setText(atitulo+" "+articulo.getConsecutivo());
    viewHolder.textViewTitulo.setText(viewHolder.textViewTitulo.getText()+" "+articulo.getTitulo());
    viewHolder.textViewContenido.setText(viewHolder.textViewContenido.getText()+" "+String.valueOf(articulo.getDias())+" días");
    DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.##");
    viewHolder.textViewCosto.setText(viewHolder.textViewCosto.getText()+" "+currency.format(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(articulo.getCosto()))));


    viewHolder.setOnClickListener();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que obtienes es:

> incompatible types. required java.lang.string found int

El problema es que no debes obtener un recurso definido en el archivo `strings.xml` de esta forma, esto es incorrecto:

```
 String atitulo = R.string.Precio_Atitulo;
```

debes obtener el valor desde el archivo `strings.xml` de esta forma:

```
String atitulo = getString(R.string.Precio_Atitulo);
```